# latexrevise not changing input file

Tags: latexdiff, changes, trackchanges

I recently have found a `.tex` file (let's call it `C.tex`) that I generated years ago with `latexdiff` to compare differences between two source `.tex` files (let's call them `A.tex` and `B.tex`). However, those two original files `A.tex` and `B.tex` that were compared are currently lost for good.

I am ok with simply accepting all changes, to resume working on this old project. So I tried: `latexrevise -a C.tex > D.tex` to generated a new file with accepted changes that appear in `C.tex`. However, I get a warning that says:

> Old Document not a complete latex file. Assuming it is a tex file with
> no preamble

And after that, the generated file `D.tex` ends up being identical to `C.tex`. That is, with no accepted or deleted changes - all the `\DIFdelbegin`, `\DIFdel`, `\DIFdelend`, `\DIFaddbegin`, `\DIFaddparts` and `\DIFaddend` stuff are still there.

The odd thing is, I am very sure that `C.tex` was never altered manually in any way. It was a direct output from `latexdiff`. So, to begin with, I have no clue why `C.tex` would not be a "complete latex file", nor do I know what that even means.

Searching online for that warning gives nothing - just the links to the Github code where the warning is introduced in the codebase. Therefore, my questions: what could be going on, and how could I try to solve this to accept all the changes?

Comment: That's not really enough to go on. Do you get more info running it with verbose outputs? `latexrevise -a -V C.tex > D.tex`. It sounds like somehow the regexp matching is not working: the first error only happens if the file cannot find a `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` pair in the TeX file. But even if that were the case, the `tex` file should still be processed as if all of it is part of the body.

Comment: @WillieWong thanks for your comment. So, I tried with `-V` parameter and got the exact same warning and unmodified output, with one extra sentence printed to the terminal: "ACCEPT mode". So, nothing useful with verbose. I also double-checked and `\begin{document` / `\end{document}` are there, like everything else.

Comment: Can you also show the output of `latexrevise --version` and `perl --version`?

Comment: @WillieWong `latexrevise --version` gives `This is LATEXREVISE 1.3.1
  (c) 2005-2020 F J Tilmann`. While `perl --version` gives `perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`.

Comment: Actually, you can also try to see if the issue is with your `C.tex` or with `latexdiff`: try creating a simple tex file, make a copy, edit it, and run them through `latexdiff`; see if that works. If it does, run `latexrevise` on the diff file generated. If all of those work, then you know the culprit is your `C.tex` file. Otherwise it is the installed version of latexdiff.

Comment: @WillieWong good idea. I tried it idea with a small paragraph with `C.tex`, saved that as a new file, altered it and run `latexdiff`. I got a bunch of warnings `utf8 "\xFF"  does not map to Unicode` and `Malformed UTF-8 character`. So, I guessed those were making `latexrevise` to not work properly. Solution that solved it all: simply copying content from `C.tex` with Ctrl+C Ctrl+P into a new blank `.tex` file and then running `latexrevise` on it worked! Obvious reason: manual copying+pasting (at least in Ubuntu) does not carry over those types of non-visible UTF8 weird chars

Comment: Probably not a non-visible UTF8 character. What is encountered is not valid unicode. Possibly because your file has secretly a different encoding. If that's the case, then an alternative to manual copying and pasting is running your file through [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv). // Since you figured it out in the end, you should consider posting an answer yourself. There may be folks who run into the same problem in the future who can benefit.

Comment: @WillieWong I will do so, thanks a lot

Comment: If whoever downvoted my question reads this: I would very much like to understand why my question got downvoted. Seriously. This is a question about an undocumented problem that some files can present with `latexrevise`, and for which I myself found an answer that I will put free time to contribute and share with the community for future reference. What a nasty website

Comment: People downvote for all sorts of different reasons; most folks are kind enough to leave a note explaining why when they do. Don't take that too much to heart and I sincerely hope that you continue to participate on this site.